# composer autoloader psr-0 namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I have create a custom composer package but I am having troubles to set the correct autoload options for it.

All my classes are under `MyNamespace/Common` namespace. So for example for including my `ArrayHelper` class I do use `Mynamespace/Common/Helper/ArrayHelper`.

This is the relevant part of my `composer.json`:

```js
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyNamespace\\": "" }
}
```

I have read this: [composer.json / autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Any help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to navigate the file location of your namespace.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyNameSpace": "./<path to your parent directory>" }
}
```

For example, this is my directory structure:

```
composer.json
source
  \-Data
    |-Controller
    \-Repository
```

Then, in the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyNameSpace": "source/Data" }
}
```

Then, I can define classes in these namespaces:

```
/* namespace for classes in controller directory */
namespace MyNameSpace\Controller;

/* namespace for classes in repository directory */
namespace MyNameSpace\Repository;
```

Comment: My package structure was similar to symfony2 compoenents so I had to configure a target dir like this: http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#target-dir

Comment: namespace definitions delimiter should use "\" not "/"